# How to delete the last gnome panel?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

How do i get rid of the last panel in Classic Gnome session in 12.04? I couldn't find any way for Precise.

Comment: What is the **"last"** Gnome Panel, out of curiosity?

Comment: when you have more than one panel, e.g one at the top of the screen and one at the bottom, the panel's right click menu allows you to delete one panel, but not the last one, i.e, there has to be at least one panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked in 11.04 so it's worth a try. Open up classic-gnome.session the example below uses nano to edit the file.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/classic-gnome.session
```

and change these two lines

```
Required=windowmanager;panel;filemanager;
Required-panel=gnome-panel
```

to this

```
Required=windowmanager;filemanager;
#Required-panel=gnome-panel
```

Then log out and back in.

Reference Links:

http://www.torypages.com/blog/?p=819

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1740597

Comment: I see this marked as answered but this does not apply to 12.04.  The lines stated above are not present in the classic-gnome.session file.
[GNOME Session]
Name=GNOME Classic
RequiredComponents=gnome-panel;gnome-settings-daemon;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=gnome-wm
DefaultProvider-notifications=notify-osd
IsRunnableHelper=/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-check-accelerated
FallbackSession=gnome-fallback
DesktopName=GNOME